# Contentful with react expected parameter accessToken error

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, access-token, gitignore, contentful

I created a contentful blog in a separate project below and would like to add my blog to my blog.js page in my main project. I sent up my Environment Variables in an .env file and my Access Token was exposed on github and I never had this problem in my gitignore file. Not sure if I have to change Set Environment Variables in Windows 10.

I also have "dotenv": "^8.2.0", and "config": "^3.3.2", as a dependency for my mini social network for my users and profile. Not sure if I have to add require('dotenv').config(); to client.js.

```
.gitignore file:

.env
node_modules/
config/default.json
.env.development
```

client.js file:

```
import * as contentful from "contentful";

export const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: process.env.REACT_APP_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_SPACE_TOKEN,
});
```

.env

```
REACT_APP_SPACE_ID=my access key 
REACT_APP_SPACE_TOKEN=my access token
```

Console error:

createClient

```
 56 |  */
  57 | function createClient(params) {
  58 |   if (!params.accessToken) {
> 59 |     throw new TypeError('Expected parameter accessToken');
  60 |   }
  61 | 
  62 |   if (!params.space) {
```

I also have a config file for my mongoDB and I'm not sure if this of sets my Contentful accesstoken

config/db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI');

const connectDB = async () => {
  try{
    await mongoose.connect(db, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false 
    });

    console.log('MongoDB Connected...');
  } catch(err){
    console.error(err.message);
    // exit process with failure
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
// db.js
module.exports = connectDB;
```

Just added my .env file path to use via the path

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('API Running'));

//DEfine Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));
app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
//server.js
```

Comment: Can you log out `process.env` using `console.log` to see if the tokens are available? It's hard to give advice without knowing your detailed setup. I assume, calling dotenv at the beginning of the script will fix it.

Comment: Just added my .env file path to use via the path

Comment: Not sure where to place my             
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID); 
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_KEY);

Comment: Do i need to add require('dotenv').config();

Comment: You can place `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID)` right before you want to use it. If this addition logs `undefined`, then you know that your environment variables are not loaded. I assume you're using create-react-app, you can find more info about environments variables here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Comment: I only recived NODE_ENV: "development" and the rest were undefined

Comment: It's very hard to tell, without looking at source code. Did you add the Contentful tokens to `.env.development`, too? I assume you're running into troubles in development?

Comment: Thanks for the advice i placed the .env.development outside of my project. I can see the contentful blog in my project

Comment: Wooohooooo! It'd be great if you could edit the question and answer it so that future people see what was the issue. :)

Comment: @stefan judis I can see and receive emails but when I run console.log(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY); in the console log I receive the value as undefined. But when i run node server.js in the terminal I can see the api key. i have a client folder with .env and .env.develoment and I can see all of my api keys in the browser console. And I have a sever folder with an .env file and this is the environment variable that I have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to add the environment variable in the right path for contentful blog you have to place in .env.development.

.env.development

```
REACT_APP_SPACE_ID=my access key 
REACT_APP_SPACE_TOKEN=my access token
```

You can risk to expose your token if you place your .env.development outside of your project. If you place console.log(process.env); in the area you want to test. Be sure to restart the server to test by placing ***npm start*** in the terminal every time you test the console.log.

client\src\client.js

```
import * as contentful from "contentful";

console.log(process.env);

export const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: process.env.REACT_APP_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.REACT_APP_SPACE_TOKEN,
});
```

If you place the environment variable in the wrong area you receive an undefined

```
Object
FAST_REFRESH: true
NODE_ENV: "development"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

If you test your .env.development file in the appropriate area you will see your  access key and access token will be displayed in the console.

```
Object
FAST_REFRESH: true
NODE_ENV: "development"
PUBLIC_URL: ""
REACT_APP_SPACE_ID: "my access key"
REACT_APP_SPACE_TOKEN: "my access token"
WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined
WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined
__proto__: Object
```